# How to give a role the permission to see a text channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a ticket command for my bot. It works fine but, only the person oned the ticket and members with admin perms can see the channel. How can I add a support role to it?
this is my current code:

**rickroll alert don't go to the youtube link in the code below**

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  voteRemind.start()
  print('Bot is ready')
  await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Streaming(name="Minecraft", url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"))

  for channel in getTicketChannels():
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Support', description="""
    To create a ticket react with  

    <:Rules:910406026543652895> **RULES:**
      Tell The Problem The Second You Open 
      Don't Wait For Us To Ask
    """)
    guild = bot.get_guild(channel[0])
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel[1])
    await channel.purge()
    msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction('')

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if user == bot.user:
      return
    guild = reaction.message.guild
    if reaction.message.channel == guild.get_channel(getTicketChannel(guild.id)):
      await reaction.remove(user)
      if discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=f"ticket-{user.display_name.lower()}"):
        return
      category = guild.get_channel(getTicketChannel(guild.id)).category
      embed = discord.Embed(title='Welcome to your ticket!', description="Support will be with you shortly.\n\n<:Rules:910406026543652895> \nTell The Problem The Second You Open \nDon't Wait For Us To Ask", color=0x1ff44d)

      overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
      }
      ticket = await category.create_text_channel(name=f'┃{user.display_name}', topic=f"{user.display_name}'s Support Channel", overwrites=overwrites)
      await ticket.send(user.mention)
      await ticket.send(embed=embed)
```

Pls let me know if you know any change to make or add `@MDA` (the name of the support role) to the channel. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `PermissionOverwrite` for the support role as well. It'll look something like this:

```py
support_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='MDA')
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
    support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True) # or whatever permissions the role should have
}
ticket = await category.create_text_channel(name=f'┃{user.display_name}', topic=f"{user.display_name}'s Support Channel", overwrites=overwrites)
```

Comment: It works so well :)